# Import and Export Contacts from Outlook with PHP in Linux

Tags: php, linux, outlook

Can anyone help me how to import and export Oulook contacts with php in Linux. I have done importing and exporting of Google contacts, but I couldn't find a way for Outlook.

Say I have an user and have a button "Add to Outlook contacts", so that on clicking the button, asks for Outlook login and contact is saved, same as Google contacts. Google is doing with OAuth.

Is there any way for Outlook alike Google?

Thanks in advance

Comment: save outlook contacts as csv file and then read that file using php

Comment: @Satya- So how can I get outlook contacts as csv through php?

Comment: check this link http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/exchange_webdav_examples.php

Comment: So basically I need a Exchange server to run the application

Comment: ideally yes but tell me one thing, are you doing this for your org or just a test app? In case you are doing this for your org then the org must be already having an exchange server.